# defernumbers=true in biblatex results in ZERO numbering for new references

Tags: biblatex, biber

I am using `biblatex` in conjunction with Biber to create several lists of references. The first time compiling produces an output where all references are numbered as expected (1, 2, ... , n), (n+1, n+2, ...), etc.

The problem: If I now add an additional reference in my .bib file, and compile again, it is numbered with ZERO, regardless of how many times I run pdflatex. To overcome this I must either:

- delete all intermediate files and do a clean compilation;
- or comment the option `defernumbers=true`, compile, then uncomment it, then compile again;

MWE

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage[style=phys, sorting=none, defernumbers=true]{biblatex}
\BiblatexSplitbibDefernumbersWarningOff
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

\begin{document}
\printbibliography[keyword=regular,heading=subbibliography,title={Other contributions}]
\nocite{*}
\end{document}
```

and

```
@article{Neugart2017,
  keywords = {regular},
  title    = {Some title},
  author   = {R. Neugart and others},
  journal  = {J. Phys. G}, 
  volume   = 44,
  pages    = 064002,
  doi      = {10.1088/1361-6471/aa6642},
  year     = 2017,
}
@article{Ruiz2017,
  keywords = {regular},
  title    = {Another title},
  author   = {R. F. {Garcia Ruiz} and C. Gorges and others},
  journal  = {J. Phys. G},
  volume   = 44,
  pages    = 044003,
  doi      = {10.1088/1361-6471/aa5a24},
  year     = 2017,
}
```

Comment: If the behaviour is indeed as you describe that would most likely be a bug. Unfortunately, it is incredibly hard to investigate issues like this without an example document. Would it be possible to show us a short, yet fully compilable example document that reproduces the behaviour (a so-called MWE https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864 or MWEB https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864).

Comment: Hello, the minimalistic example can be downloaded from here:

Comment: https://ipnshare.in2p3.fr/owncloud/index.php/s/vmWv2yEb5TFFHWj

Comment: Please post your example document directly in the question (usually it is possible to minimise the code so that it comfortably fits into the character limit). Links to external sites for code examples are strongly discouraged and I won't open those links as a matter of principle.

Comment: %main.tex
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage[style=phys,sorting=none
,defernumbers=true
]{biblatex}
\BiblatexSplitbibDefernumbersWarningOff
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

\begin{document}
\printbibliography[keyword=regular,heading=subbibliography,title={Other contributions}]
\nocite{*}
\end{document}

Comment: %bibliography.bib
@article{Neugart2017,
    keywords =  {regular},
    title = {Some title},
    author = {R. Neugart and others},
    journal = {J. Phys. G},
    volume = 44,
    pages = 064002,
    doi = {10.1088/1361-6471/aa6642},
    year =  2017}
  
@article{Ruiz2017,
    keywords = {regular},
    title = {Another title},
    author = {R. F. {Garcia Ruiz} and C. Gorges and others},
    journal = {J. Phys. G},
    volume = 44,
    pages = 044003,
    doi = {10.1088/1361-6471/aa5a24},
    year = 2017}

Comment: Thank you for the example. I have edited into your question to make it easier to read and so people don't have to go through the comments to see the important code. I'll have a look at the problem later today.

Comment: Reported at https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/1067

Answer (score 2):

This was a bug with how `biblatex` recalculated labelnumber data if `\nocite{*}` was involved. The issue is discussed at https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/1067
and should be resolved in `biblatex` v3.16 (released 2020-12-31 and available now in TeX live and MikTeX).

Update your TeX system.